I am trying to connect google spreadsheets with discord.js though javascript
I want to use Google spreadsheets as a database for a discord bot (using javascript).
I had used it before like this:

I created credentials to use Google Spreadsheet as API and the JSON file had this format:
{
 "type": "",
 "project_id": "",
 "private_key_id": "",
 "private_key": "",
 "client_email": "",
 "client_id": "",
 "auth_uri": "",
 "token_uri": "",
 "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "",
 "client_x509_cert_url": ""
}


I used the following code to initiate the spreadsheet:
const { GoogleSpreadsheet } = require('google-spreadsheet'); 
const sheet = require('./sheet.json') // The credentials JSON
const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet(<ID Spreadsheet>);

async function initSheet()
{
  await doc.useServiceAccountAuth(sheet);
  await doc.loadInfo()
}

bot.on('ready', () => { 
 initSheet()
})



NOW, I tried to do the same but it has changed:

I started following this guide: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js

Enable the API
Authorize credentials for a web application
Create an API key
Create a service account



The credentials now look like this:
{"web":
   {
    "client_id":"",
    "project_id":"",
    "auth_uri":"",
    "token_uri":"",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"",
    "client_secret":""
   }
}


For the code this time I tried several options with different errors, installing :

The Setup Example, but I do not have an HTML so had to adapt it: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js#set_up_the_sample
ERROR: gapi is not defined

The basics from this guide: https://theoephraim.github.io/node-google-spreadsheet/#/
ERROR: You must initialize some kind of auth before making any requests

The OAuth 2.0 authentication: https://theoephraim.github.io/node-google-spreadsheet/#/guides/authentication
ERROR: fetchUserGoogleCredsFromDatabase() is not defined





I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand Before I was using doc.useServiceAccountAuth(credentials); and all worked perfectly, but now that the credentials form has changed this does not work anymore.. Also, I cannot understand the relationship between your showing script and I am trying to connect google spreadsheets with discord.js though javascript. Can I ask you about the details of them? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Hello, I have rewritten the question to put more detail on all the problem. Hope it is more clear now.

Thank you for replying. In your updated question, it seems that you are trying to use the access token from the service account and the OAuth2. In your actual expected result, which do you want to use the service account or the OAuth2?

As far as I understand I need both, the service account that is the link to the google spreadsheet and the auth to get access.
